# Angular - how to get variable from local PHP file

Tags: php, angular

I want to get variable from my *getData.php* file that is in src/assets folder of angular project.

```
<?php 

...

echo json_encode('test');
?>
```

*get-data.service* :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class GetDataService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getTest(): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get('assets/getData.php')
                 .map(response => response.json());
    }
}
```

*app.component* :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { GetDataService } from './services/get-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(private getDataService: GetDataService) { }

    title = 'Run Chart Generator';
    data;

    getTestTwo() {
        this.getDataService.getTest()
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.data = data;
                console.log(this.data)
            });
    }
}
```

When I call function *getTestTwo* I've got:

`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

---

When I change php from `echo json_encode('test')` to `echo 'test'` and service from `.map(response => response.json())` to `.map(response => response)` then I've got in console:

`Object { _body: "<?php   include('simple_html_dom.ph…", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Object, type: 2, url: "http://localhost:4200/assets/getDat…" }`

**How can I retrieve a variable from my *php* file?**

*@angular/cli: 1.4.1*
*@angular/core: 4.3.6*

Comment: I found that PHP JSON encoding is incorrect, you may have to create a method to do that manually. I recommend you use angular `console.log(JSON.stringify("test"))` and compare that to PHP echo of `json_encode("test")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP file won't work under a NodeJS project.
You need to separate your Angular App from your server logic. Use Nginx or Apache to serve your PHP file, then you will be able to call it in your getTest() function.